# Errors when reducing VARCHAR length

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    ID int identity not null, 
    Name VARCHAR(100), 
    Age int, 
    EyeColour varchar(20), 
    primary key (ID)
)

CREATE INDEX Name ON Person (Name)
CREATE INDEX Age ON Person (Age)
CREATE INDEX EyeColour ON Person (EyeColour)
```

I can execute the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE person
ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(110)
```

However, I cannot execute the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE person
ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(90)
```

The error is:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The index 'Name' is dependent on column 'name'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN name failed because one or more objects access this column.

Why am I seeing these errors when I reduce the length of a `VARCHAR`. In what other scenarios would I see this error e.g. change a data type?

Is there an automated way of identifying all the indexes and constraints affected by a data type change and dealing with them?

Comment: Do you really need to index all three fields, or is that just a simplified example?

Comment: Delete the index, alter table, create index... Make profit.

Comment: @HardCode, yes it is simplified so I could get my point across.

Comment: You could automate this by building a process that checks the [system tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175105.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely automate the identification part. Here is a script that will find all the indices and foreign keys depending on a table column (I have left finding check constraints as an exercise for the reader). As it is a script, you would have to change the parameters when you run it. You could also turn this into a stored procedure.

However, I don't recommend automating the actions such as dropping indices or constraints. You are better off reviewing the output and deciding if it is really OK to reduce the sizes of the columns or not in the light of what you know about the applications that use these data.

```
-- parameters
DECLARE
    @nm_schema sysname = N'Purchasing',
    @nm_table sysname = N'PurchaseOrderHeader',
    @nm_column sysname = N'EmployeeID';

DECLARE
    @id_table int,
    @id_column smallint;

SELECT @id_table = o.object_id
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s
        ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE o.name = @nm_table
        AND s.name = @nm_schema
        AND o.type = 'U';

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Schema %s table %s not found', 0, 1, @nm_schema, @nm_table);
    RETURN;
END;

SELECT @id_column = column_id
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = @id_table
        AND name = @nm_column;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Column %s not found in schema %s table %s', 0, 2, @nm_column, @nm_schema, @nm_table);
    RETURN;
END;

SELECT 'Index' AS 'dependency', i.name
    FROM sys.indexes i
    JOIN sys.index_columns ic
        ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
        AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    WHERE i.object_id = @id_table
        AND ic.column_id = @id_column
        AND NOT i.type = 0 -- heap
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FKey', f.name
    FROM sys.foreign_keys f
    JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc
        ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
    WHERE (f.parent_object_id = @id_table AND fc.parent_column_id = @id_column)
        OR (f.referenced_object_id = @id_table AND fc.referenced_column_id = @id_column);
```